# Keras custom loss per one instance

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Here is the original dice function:

```
def dice_coefficient_(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true_f * y_pred_f), axis=-1)

    return (2. * intersection) / (
        K.sum(K.square(y_true_f), -1) + K.sum(K.square(y_pred_f), -1) + 1e-8)
```

The shape of y_true and y_pred : (batch size, 1, 128, 160, 128)

Loss = -1 * dice_coefficient

**I'm trying to edit the function so that it calculates a loss value per one instance and returns the averaged values.**

The reason i want to edit this is that the current function is affected by batch size. When batch size increases, dice increases also.

**How do i edit the code in this case?** I tried to use for loop but a person said "Don't use for loop.".

Comment: what do you mean per instance?. For each data value in a batch?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly, you need average instead of sum in the final line.

Simply replace the last line with the following. From the looks that's the only line where an aggregation takes place on the batch-dimension.

```
return (2. * intersection) / (
        K.mean(K.square(y_true_f), -1) + K.mean(K.square(y_pred_f), -1) + 1e-8)
```